# What is the name of this game that appears to be a screen full of dots?

Tags: game-identification, mobile

Does anyone know what the name of the game in this picture is?

I just have this picture and want to get it, but I don't know any other info about it.

[image: game in question]

Comment: For anyone who sees the edit summary, my phone changed "retag" to "death"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That would be the game Ballz available on both [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ketchapp.ballz&hl=en) and [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ballz/id1139609950?mt=8)

[image]